# Mitigating HSTS Bypass

Tags: apache-2.4, rhel7, hsts

Friends,

Is there any way to prevent HSTS bypass on Apache/RHEL environment. I have a webserver with valid SSL certificate for the domain. Non HTTPS requests are being redirected to HTTPS. Necessary headers including Content Security Policy, Strict Transport Security, X-Frame are applied already.

Any ideas?

Adding an example link shows how to achive HSTS Bypass

https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/defeating-hsts-and-bypassing-https-with-dns-server-changes-and-mitmf-0162322/

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you mean by HSTS bypass?  What's your threat model?

Comment: Not all clients (especially bots) will obey that header.  As @ezra-s mentioned, you should redirect all port 80 traffic if you can, at least for anything that could contain sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks womble, ezra-s, Aaron for the reply and suggestions., @womble please refer the link https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/defeating-hsts-and-bypassing-https-with-dns-server-changes-and-mitmf-0162322/

Comment: You put your domain on the HSTS preload list.

Answer (score 2):

Submit your domain here 
https://hstspreload.org/

This stops most modern browsers even *trying* to connect via http.

use sslstrip to verify, its pretty easy to set up with firefox

`sslstrip.py -l <listenPort>`

then set up firefox to proxy everything to that port

You should see the attack in action then

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed.

Don't serve anything in http, but redirects to https.

Comment: Thank you, I'm already redirecting all the non-https requests to https. Still our pen-testers found that a MITM attack possible